# jquery validation plugin remote method

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to validate a field `"organization.mailDomain"` with jquery form validation plugin. My rules for validation are

```
rules : {
        "organization.name" : {
            required : true
        },
        "organization.mailDomain" : {
            required : true,
            remote : {
                url : "/domain/check",
                type : "post",
                contentType : "application/json",
                data : {mailDomain : $("#mailDomain").val()}
            }
        }
```

what i want is to send data as `mailDomain=gmail.com` but my current code is sending data as  `organization.mailDomain=abc.com&mailDomain=gmail.com`.
I know if i change field name from (`organization.mailDomain`) to (`mailDomain`) it will work, but i need the field name as it is.

UPDATE : By default the value is "gmail.com" but when i change the value to "abc.com" the post data is `organization.mailDomain=abc.com&mailDomain=gmail.com`

UPDATE : i am getting following error on server side

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('o' (code 111)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
```

can any one kindly help me?????

Answer (score 1):

In order to pass dynamic data to the remote function, you can pass a function as the data value, which will return the desired value... this function will get evaluated whenever the validator is called

```
remote: {
    url: "/domain/check",
    type: "post",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: {
        mailDomain: function () {
            return $("#mailDomain").val()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply, now i am getting the dynamic data, now the post data is still "organization.mailDomain=abc.com&mailDomain=abc.com", how can i post just "mailDomain=abc.com".